# Angularjs form in controller always undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

In my project I use ui-view and with following structure (deleted unnecessary code):

```
<main class="content">
    <div class="inner" ng-controller="OrderPageController">
        <div ui-view="main-info"></div>
        <div ui-view="comments"></div>
        <div ui-view="bids-list"></div>
        <div ui-view="add-bid"></div>
    </div>
</main>
```

And in add-bid view:

```
<form name="newbidform" novalidate ng-submit="postNewBid(newbidform);">
   <input type="text" ng-model="newbid.bid" required>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

So, then I submit form I try to check if all of required inputs are valid:

```
$scope.postNewBid = function(form) {

console.log(form) // $valid and $invalid always undefined
console.log($scope.newbidform) // always undefined

        // check validity before send
        if (!form.$valid) {
            angular.forEach(form.$error, function (field) {
                angular.forEach(field, function(errorField){
                    errorField.$setTouched();
                })
            });
            $scope.failedSubmit = true;
            return false;
        } else {
            $scope.failedSubmit = false;
        } 
// other things if form is valid
```

So, the problem the form is always undefined (at all or $valid/$invalid attr). I tried to use formName as parameter in function, as $scope.formName variable (always undefined), and define controller twice, in second time on form:

```
<form name="newbidform" novalidate ng-submit="postNewBid();" ng-controller="OrderPageController">
```

Actually, it works, but when I'm trying to access other variables in controller - I can't. So, is there a way to get a form state in controller in AngularJs? Thanks

Comment: It would be significantly easier to help you if you could please create a working plunker.  Thanks.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/byV32EEXTugHRp5vDvuE?p=preview

Comment: How did plunker help you, tell me please :) I have the same situation, sometimes $valid/$invalid is ok and sometimes it's undefined. I can't find out when this situation occurs.

Answer (score 1):

newbid is the variable you want to get, right ?

Try :

```
<form name="newbidform" novalidate ng-submit="postNewBid(newbid);">
```

Comment: newbidform is a name of form and a parameter for postNewBid() function, and yes, I try to get form $valid/$invalid state

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your form is nested in  child scope such as inside an `ng-include` or `ng-if` in which case since the form object doesn't exist in the parent scope the parent won't see it when angular creates it in the child.

You can fix it by simply creating an empty object in the parent controller and that object will be inherited by child scopes. Since the object exists now, a new object won;t need to be created and all the properties will get added to the reference in child scope.

```
$scope.newbidform ={};
$scope.postNewBid = function(form) {...
```

Comment: I already tried to do it, but didn't succeed. I have only one controller in this views (OrderpageController) and so I've defined $scope.newbidform ={}; , but on submit I got the same - form in function has undefined $valid/$invalid, $scope.newbidfrom staying {}

Comment: A demo that replicates this would help

Comment: It's really strange, but in plunker parameter in function works correctly -http://plnkr.co/edit/byV32EEXTugHRp5vDvuE?p=preview

Comment: hard to help if can't replicate. Here's helpful trick in view `<pre>{{newbidform|json}}</pre>` .. can see the form object when issues arise

Comment: Thanks for help, plunker helped me to understand the problem :) The problem was in my custom directive which is to reconcile two values when entering.